# what is the inverse of time.asctime in Python

Tags: python, time

I have a 24-character string and want to get the tuple.

E.g.:

```
'Fri Apr 25 12:24:47 2014'
```

(via `time.ctime(time.time())`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`time.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) parses strings into time tuples again; the default parse format matches the output of `time.ctime()` and `time.asctime()`:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(time.time())
'Fri Apr 25 12:12:06 2014'
>>> time.strptime(time.ctime(time.time()))
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=12, tm_min=12, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=115, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strptime(time.asctime())
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=12, tm_min=13, tm_sec=6, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=115, tm_isdst=-1)
```